# How to do NOT LIKE in mongoDB? $regex and $nin does not work together?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

How to do NOT LIKE in mongoDB?

```
$paddress = new MongoRegex("/kendriya/");
$caddress = new MongoRegex("/India/");

 Array 
 (
 [$and] => Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [permanent_address] => Array
                (
                    [$not] => $paddress
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [current_address] => Array
                (
                    [$not] => $caddress
                )

        )
        )
        )
```

I want implement `$nin` with regex to full text search but `$nin` and `$regex` not worked together.

Update: this is not a duplicate question. When I pass above array then result not getting because it is encode into json then it is convert into as

```
$and : 
[
{ permanent_address: { $not: "/kendriya/" } } ,
{ current_address: { $not:  "/India/" } } 
]
}
]
```

result not getting from above json array but actual mongodb syntax is

```
$and : 
[
{ permanent_address: { $not: /kendriya/ } } ,
{ current_address: { $not:  /India/ } } 
]
}
]
```

so how can I solve this?

Comment: $paddress = "/kendriya/";
$caddress ="/India/";

 Array 
 (
 [$and] => Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [permanent_address] => Array
                (
                    [$not] => $paddress
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [current_address] => Array
                (
                    [$not] => $caddress
                )

        )
        )
        )

Comment: when i use above code and pass this array  to find function then it doesn't return any records...i think its encode the array then backslash added to string value with double quoates thats why mongo doesn't return any records